# How to update web apps connection strings with Azure REST Api

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I'm trying to connect a Azure Webapp to a SQL Database provided through Azure REST API. So I'm trying to implement this request : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateconnectionstrings.

But I don't succed to create the body of the request

Comment: Share your code snippet you have tried please.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you set the wrong json body data. The below is my test connection string, the `connections` is the string name and the `connections` contains a [ConnStringValueTypePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateconnectionstrings#connstringvaluetypepair).

```
{"properties": {
    "connections": {
      "value": "test1",
      "type": "SQLAzure"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

And also it could update the string to Azure.

[image]